# Does every division algebra appear as the endomorphism ring of some group representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, division-algebras

One way to read [Schur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) is

> The endomorphism ring of an irreducible representation of a finite group over a field $K$ is a division algebra over $K$.

For $K=\Bbb R$ there are easy examples where the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to either $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb H$ (the quaternions). For $K=\Bbb C$ there is not much to check as there are no non-trivial finite-dimensional division algebras.

What is the general situation? Can every division agebra be realized as an endomorphism ring of some representation?

> **Qustion:** Given a finite-dimensional division algebra $\mathfrak A$ over $K$, is there a representation of a finite group over $K$ whose endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $\mathfrak A$?.

Comment: A suppose you want to restrict to *associative* division algebras. After all, the endomorphism ring is always associative